# How do you convert column of data frame from factor to character

Tags: r

I get a database query returned to my and I need to make sure the columns are not factors.

Here is a toy model:

```
d<-data.frame(x = c(1,2),y=factor(c("d","e")),stringAsFactors= FALSE)
class(d$y)  #### you can see that it is a factor and I need it to be a character
```

In my real world case column y is not set as a factor, I just look at it an it is a factor. Something like

```
MyDataFrame<- DatabaseQuery(....)
class(MyDataFrame) -> this = "data frame"
class(MyDataFrame$y) ->  this = factor
```

So...how can I convert column y in this data frame to a factor?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I'm missing something here, but there is a tool called [Google](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=convert+factor+to+character+r&oq=convert+factor+to+charac&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j69i60.7554j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl) ?

Comment: Downvoted because this is one of the RFAQs. There is sentiment against this fortune but some may find it interesting: `fortunes::fortune("WTFM")`. On the other hand it may be why R-traffic on SO is higher than on Rhelp.

Answer (score 1):

Try `MyDataFrame$y <- as.character(MyDataFrame$y)`.
This will convert everything to characters.

Comment: If you run these 2 lines as.character(d$y)
class(d$y)   you will see that "y" is still a factor. Any ideas why?

Comment: @user3022875 you need to assign it to `d$y` first... i.e. `d$y <- as.character(d$y); class(d$y)`